# Pila con Plantillas

Tags: c++

Tengo un error en la clase nodo, cuando esta la intento hacer con plantillas

el error que me dice: template arguments required for class Pila

Clase Nodo:

```
#ifndef NODO_H_INCLUDED
#define NODO_H_INCLUDED
#include <stdlib.h>
template <class T>
class Nodo{
private:
    T Valor;
    Nodo<T> *siguiente;
public:
    Nodo(T v){
        this->Valor=v;
        this->siguiente=NULL;
    }
    void setSiguiente(Nodo<T> *sig){
        this->siguiente=sig;
    }
friend class Pila;
};

#endif // NODO_H_INCLUDED
```

Clase Pila:

```
#ifndef PILA_H_INCLUDED
#define PILA_H_INCLUDED
#include "Nodo.h"
template <class T>
class Pila{
    private:
        Nodo<T> *Primero;
        Nodo<T> *Ultimo;
        bool PilaVacia(){
            return (this->Primero==NULL);
        }
    public:
        Pila(){
            this->Primero=NULL;
            this->Ultimo=NULL;
        }

        void Meter(T n){
            Nodo<T> *nuevo=new Nodo<T>(n);
            if(this->PilaVacia()){
                this->Primero=nuevo;
            }
            else{
                this->Ultimo->setSiguiente(nuevo);
            }
            this->Ultimo=nuevo;
        }
};


#endif // PILA_H_INCLUDED
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Pila.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Pila<int> pl;
    pl.Meter(1);
    cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

[[image: El error me manda a la linea siguiente1]

De momento es el esquema que debo hacer , no se porque me manda a ese error, no encuentro una solucion , tambien no se porque no reconoce la clase Pila como amiga, si ya tiene el friend class Pila

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nota que en el archivo `Nodo` estás declarando la clase Pila mediante:

```
friend class Pila;
```

Esto te trae conflictos con la definición de `Pila` ya que uno es una plantilla y el otro no. Debes usar simplemente el nombre de la clase:

```
friend Pila;
```

Pero como `Pila` es una plantilla no puedes hacer que todas las especializaciones de `Pila` sean amigas de la clase. Solo de una a la vez que es lo único que necesitas:

```
friend Pila<T>;
```

Además en la clase `Nodo` no hay ningún `#include` de la clase `Pila`. Así que para evitar problemas de inclusión cíclica mejor quita esa línea y escribe esta otra en el archivo de la clase `Pila`:

```
friend Nodo<T>;
```

Te quedaría algo así:

Nodo.h

```
template <class T>
class Nodo{
    ...
}
```

Pila.h

```
#include "Pila.h"
template <class T>
class Pila {
    ...
    friend Nodo<T>;
}
```

Por cierto, por ahora no necesitas que las clases sean amigas ya que no estás accediendo a ninguna variable o función privada de la otra.

---

El código quedaría así:

Nodo.h

```
template <class T>
class Nodo{
private:
    T Valor;
    Nodo<T> *siguiente;
public:
    Nodo(T v){
        this->Valor=v;
        this->siguiente=NULL;
    }
    void setSiguiente(Nodo<T> *sig){
        this->siguiente=sig;
    }
};
```

Pila.h

```
#include "Nodo.h"
template <class T>
class Pila{
    private:
        Nodo<T> *Primero;
        Nodo<T> *Ultimo;
        bool PilaVacia(){
            return (this->Primero==NULL);
        }
    public:
        Pila(){
            this->Primero=NULL;
            this->Ultimo=NULL;
        }

        void Meter(T n){
            Nodo<T> *nuevo=new Nodo<T>(n);
            if(this->PilaVacia()){
                this->Primero=nuevo;
            }
            else{
                this->Ultimo->setSiguiente(nuevo);
            }
            this->Ultimo=nuevo;
        }

    friend Nodo<T>;
};
```

Puedes ver otros errores que pueden ser más claros en [otro compilador](https://godbolt.org/z/MPzv7fhG7) y probarlo [aquí](https://tio.run/##fZI9b8MgEIZ3/wqaLnalVO0af8wd0ihSnezEvqRIGBBgZ4jy210M/sJRc4MF9@Ln7j0ohFgXFLNL274SVtC6BJQQrrQEXGVBoKESFGuTNKeUQnkWuMWOl/wWCEkao24CZCJHR0y5jO2m05M8Q2@KXGoCTEMciPpESbEZ9TBHTXSz2y70L1HrzDLSJl6kR0y6O2y3Tr3bb8NJiRTon@FEOK/9wJ9AZjVw7vETq3tCsaN4dj2Xe0kqkDx@VA5Uk2omnDinFnnEBcHhrL8uJOhaMhS6Xntqaj1HE8MZn4@ziw665PmcaXS@7npcyPdgXNoRf4MGaa6MLUqMTlkNDU8ZXIdUyCK/GjkPxib/C9pj0xbrc@7eDqiC/yDOmbn1@fuwxOgZ0hvLooF@LmdpYOVgNbZPqFaEXRDDFSiBC0BKlyZLmEYVJiyMAtdm5z4x2QwJ6riCvrvxfvZtFbzWKEnQ6gso5ejKJS1fVl3GFO1/6t/Kh6ndtn8).

Comment: Excelent tu respuesta,me ha ayudado para quitar el metodo setSiguiente de la clase Nodo, pero siempre me sigue dando el error de aparece en la imagen adjuta:  template arguments required for class Pila

Comment: Listo, tu respuesta de verificar en otros compiladores me ayudo. Gracias